# NSArray - Memory Leak how to?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

I have function which return NSArray, but it's generating memory leak, since i can't release the array after return line how can I release it? 
Thanks.

```
-(NSArray *)readDataFromDatabase
{

   return NSArray;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

autorelease the array before returning:

```
- (NSArray*) readDataFromDatabase 
{
  // option 1: create an auto-released array
  NSArray* a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: ...];
  return a;

  // option 2: autorelease manually
  NSArray* aa = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: ...] autorelease];
  return aa;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [apple's docs for `autorelease`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html)

Comment: i did, return [arrayNextQuestion autorelease]; but it crash the app.

Comment: got it. i was releasing objects inside array before the array. now i understood autorelease does all, not just the array. leak fixed. many thanks.